# Disable auto scale for Visiblox chart

Tags: zooming, scale, visiblox

I have a dynamic chart where you cna change the chart in real time by dragging dots on the line, but since Visiblox have some kind of auto scale/zoom its quite unusable.

I've tried AutoScaleToVisibleData = false on the two axis, but it does not do anything... I have a ZoomBehaviour and still want to be able to zoom, but I do not want it to be auto

Answer (score 1):

AutoScaleToVisibleData determines whether the scale on one axis should be dependent on the scale of another (e.g. only show a scale for the y-axis that encompases what is currently visible on the x-axis).

To fix the range (and disable auto-ranging) of the data you need to set an explicit range to the axis. See http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/03/visiblox-charts-ranges-demystified for more info.

Also you may want to have a quick look at http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/09/creating-a-custom-behaviour-part-1 since that sounds a bit like what you want?